# Google lighthouse - Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy for webp

Tags: caching, webp, lighthouse

Since yesterday somehow on all my websites the webp images are shown with a Cache TTL of 1 h, even I set differently in my htaccess on my own hosting and also the same happens in firebase.

Just few days ago it worked perfectly for all images.

All other images are cached correctly for 1 year. Is there any change by Chrome?

Thanks for any information

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It came out that there was problem with the nginX server, after restart everything works fine.